# How to change the label font size dynamically?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I wrote some wpf application that contain labels.
I want to change the label font size according to the screen .. that mean that if the user will maximize the application window - the font will grow up - if he will change the size to small window - the font will shrink.

I try a lot of solutions - but the font size is not changing.

need help ...

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want your application to look the same whatever the window size is? As a stretched bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a ViewBox

```
 <Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <Label >Hello world</Label>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: useful attribute to prevent too big font size:
  `<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly"`

Answer (score 2):

Using FormattedText class, you can find out Width and Height of given text with specified Fontfamily. You can use this method to calculate and find out how much font size is needed to fill up available space.